# Class template can be instantiated without members?

Tags: c++, templates

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) says this:

> instantiating a class template does not cause its member definitions to be instantiated.

I can't imagine any class in C++ being instantiated, whether from a template or not, where that classes members were not also instantiated?

Comment: This applies to member functions. But I can imagine if you call a static method of a class template, data members need not be instantiated either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many early C++ compilers instantiated all member functions, whether you ever called them or not.

Consider, for example, `std::list`, which has a `sort` member function. With a current, properly functioning compiler, you can instantiate `list` over a type that doesn't support comparison. If you try to use `list::sort`, it will fail, because you don't support comparison. As long as you don't call `sort` for that list, it's all fine though, because `list<T>::sort` won't be instantiated unless you call it.

With those older, poorly functioning compilers, however, trying to create `list<T>` meant that `list<T>::sort` was instantiated even though you never used it. The existence of `list::sort` meant that you needed to implement `<` for `T`, just to create a `list<T>`, even if you never actually used `sort` on a list of that type at all.

Answer (score 1):

The standard clearly says that (both non-template and template) member methods instantiation should happen only when used.

An excerpt from C++ standard (N3690 - 14.7.1(2) Implicit instantiation)

2 Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member **is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist**; in particular, the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Methods of a class are also members. Class Template methods are instantiated when they are called for that instantiated class. So it is possible that those member methods are never instantiated.