# Safety of reinterpret_cast on pointer to template aggregate type

Tags: c++, casting

I would like to know if my following use of `reinterpret_cast` is undefined behaviour.

Given a template aggregate such as ...

```
template<typename T>
struct Container
{
  Container(T* p) : ptr(p) { }
  ...
  T* ptr;
};
```

... and a type hierarchy like ...

```
struct A { };
struct B : A { };
```

Is the following cast safe, given that `B` is a dynamic type of `A` ...

```
Container<B>* b = new Container<B>( new B() );
Container<A>* a = reinterpret_cast<Container<A>*>(b);
```

... in so far as that I can now safely use `a->ptr` and its (possibly virtual) members?

The code where I use this compiles and executes fine (Clang, OS X) but I'm concerned that I've placed a ticking bomb. I guess every instance of `Container<T>` shares the same layout and size so it shouldn't be a problem, right?

Looking at what cppreference.com says about `reinterpret_cast`, there seems to be a statement for legal use that covers what I'm trying to do ...

> Type aliasing
>   When a pointer or reference to object of type T1 is reinterpret_cast (or C-style cast) to a pointer or reference to object of a different type T2, the cast always succeeds, but the resulting pointer or reference may only be accessed if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout types and one of the following is true:
>
> ...
>
> T2 is an aggregate type or a union type which holds one of the aforementioned types as an element or non-static member (including, recursively, elements of subaggregates and non-static data members of the contained unions): this makes it safe to cast from the first member of a struct and from an element of a union to the struct/union that contains it.

I appreciate that it looks like I'm going the wrong way about this. That's not what I'm concerned about. I'd just like to know if what I'm doing is safe / legal or not. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Derive Container<B> from Container<A> and that would work automatically. However, this is still not save, because you can insert a C (which is another type derived from A) into a Container<A>, and then you end up with a C in a Container<B>, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: That would be great if I were just dealing with types `A` and `B` but I'd like to abstract this for any type `T`, and derivatives of `T` too.

Comment: The issue remains: If you convert a `Container<Derived>` to a mutable reference to a `Container<Base>`, you loose the guarantee that the elements in the container are of the `Derived` type. This problem exists regardless of *how* you achieve this conversion, i.e. it is the same if you brute force (reinterpret_cast) or use the suggested method of deriving the containers from each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there seems to be a statement for legal use that covers what I'm trying to do ...

That's not what that exception says or means. That exception says that given

```
struct S { int i; } s;
```

you can use `*reinterpret_cast<int *>(&s)` to access `s.i`.

There is no similar exception for what you're trying to do. What you're trying to do is simply not valid in C++. Even the below is invalid:

```
struct S { int i; };
struct T { int i; };
int f(S s) { return ((T &) s).i; }
```

and compilers optimise based on the assumption that you don't write code like that.

For an actual example that fails at run-time with a current compiler:

```
#include <cstdlib>
struct S { int i; };
struct T { int i; };
void f(S *s, T *t) { int i = s->i; t->i++; if (s->i == i) std::abort(); }
```

Here, GCC optimises away the check `s->i == i` (GCC 4.9.2, with `-O2` in the command-line options), and unconditionally calls `std::abort()`, because the compiler knows that `s` and `t` cannot possibly point to the same region of memory. Even though you might try to call it as

```
int main() { S s = { 0 }; f(&s, reinterpret_cast<T *>(&s)); }
```

Comment: Great stuff. The `s->i == i` proof nails it. My test was with `-O0` and I guess that was the worrying part. Thank you.

Comment: Why does this work? #include <cstdlib>
struct S { int i[1]; };
struct T { int i[1]; };
void f(S *s, T *t) { int i = s->i[0]; t->i[0]++; if (s->i[0] == i) std::abort(); }
int main() {
 S s = { 0 };
 f(&s, reinterpret_cast<T *>(&s)); 
}

Comment: @nachum By "work", you mean it doesn't abort for you? At the `-O2` level that I specified in my answer, it shows an unconditional call to abort in all versions of GCC since 4.9 on https://gcc.godbolt.org/.

Comment: Ah, clang on MacOS High Sierra (Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)) doesn't abort. But it aborted your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the type aliasing is legal according to the standard, you may have other issues.

> I guess every instance of `Container<T>` shares the same layout and
>   size so it shouldn't be a problem, right?

Actually, not every instance of `Container<T>` shares the same layout! As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684102/class-template-can-be-instantiated-without-members), template members are only created if they are used, so your `Container<A>` and `Container<B>` might have different memory layouts if different members are used for each type.

Comment: Yes, that would be true if I specialised `Container` for certain types - I get that - but in this case there's only ever `ptr` for any type `T`

Comment: It's not only if you specialize.  Members (both member functions and member variables) might be left out in different instantiations.  In the other question I linked to they use the example of instantiating a `std::list<T>` with a type that cannot be sorted.  As long as `std::list<T>::sort` is never called, the class will compile.  Additionally, lets say you use 3 member variables of `Container<B>` but only two member variables of `Container<A>`.  Their memory layouts might not be compatible.  Also, if you used different methods on each class then method addresses might not line up and you...

Comment: ..might end up jumping into the wrong function or the middle of a function when you call a member function on one class. (not as sure about the member function case, but I am positive about the member variable case).

Comment: I can see your reasoning. I guess I'm more concerned about the use of `ptr`, not the actual `Container` type itself. You're absolutely right that use of `Container` would be risky but in this case, it only ever serves as a wrapper for `ptr`. Appreciate your input.